# Problems in trying to decode through statistics

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode

My goal is to decode a message with the statistics of letters occurrence in the French language. For that, I created a first function which creates a string in decreasing order of occurrence in the text. Then, I match the index of the characters and I change each character with the one corresponding to the French language. The problem is that the text comes out unchanged in the console. I am a beginner in programming and any help on my mistakes or inaccuracies are appreciated. Thanks !!!

```
    import string

texte = f"""iwnspa rynjjdj arg sj hjuajhask awaigkhihaj ag sj ongyaonghihaj ps vvha rhaiwa, rdsqajg idjrhpaka
idooa wa xaka pa wn gyadkha pa w’hjbdkonghdj. hw arg ja wa 30 nqkhw 1916 n xagdrlaf, pnjr wa
ohiyhunj. rdj xaka arg sj csua, ag rn oaka arg wa xkdqhrask ps wfiaa pa unfwdkp, sja nsgka qhwwa
ps ohiyhunj. hw agspha n w’sjhqakrhga ps ohiyhunj ds hw rshg sj pdszwa iskrsr aj awaigkhihga
ag aj ongyaonghmsar. hw dzghajg sja whiajia pnjr iar pasv phrihxwhjar aj 1936, nqnjg pa xdskrshqka
rar agspar ns kaxsga ohg (onrrniysraggr hjrghgsga db gaiyjdwduf ). hw rdsghajg aj 1940 sja
gyara pa pdigdkng aj ongyaonghmsar (awwa xdkgnhg rsk par nxxwhinghdjr par ongyaonghmsar n
wn uajaghmsa) ag sj oaodhka pa onrgak aj awaigkhihga. rh wn xkaohaka bsg wnkuaoajg hujdkaa,
wn raidjpa,msh avxwhmsa idooajg sghwhrak war nwuazkar pa zddwa xdsk w’njnwfra par rhujnsv
awaigkhmsar, arg kargaa iawazka. aj 1941, hw arg aoznsiya pnjr war wnzdkngdhkar pa wn idoxnujha
pa gawaxydja ngg zaww. hooaphngaoajg, hw gknqnhwwa rsk par xkdcagr aj whnhrdj nqai war
rakqhiar raikagr, msh wsh bdjg jdgnooajg nzdkpak par msarghdjr pa ikfxgduknxyha. aj 1949, hw
ra onkha; xnk wn rshga, hw nskn gkdhr ajbnjgr. rynjjdj gknqnhwwa nsv wnzdkngdhkar pa zaww
csrms’aj 1971. xnknwwawaoajg n iawn, hw arg nsrrh xkdbarrask ns ohg pa 1958 n 1978. rynjjdj
idoxkajpmsa gdsga pdjjaa, oaoa wn qdhv ds par honuar, xasg ra gknjroaggka n w’nhpa p’sja rshga
pa 0 ag pa 1 (war zhgr), dsqknjg wn qdha nsv idoosjhinghdjr jsoakhmsar ag jdj xwsr njnwduhmsar.
hw odjgka nsrrh idooajg wa bnhg p’ncdsgak iakgnhjr zhgr n sj oarrnua xasg xakoaggka pa qakhbhak
msa war nsgkar djg aga idkkaigaoajg gknjrohr (dj xnkwa pa idpa idkkaigask p’akkaskr). hw n
kais pa jdozkasv ydjjaskr, pdjg wn oapnhwwa jnghdjnwa par rihajiar par onhjr ps xkarhpajg cdyjrdj
aj 1966, ag wa xkhv lfdgd aj 1985. n wn bhj pa rn qha, hw rdsbbka pa wn onwnpha p’nwtyahoak,
ia msh wa idjpshg pnjr sja onhrdj pa kaxdr ps onrrniysraggr. hw f paiapa wa 24 baqkhak 2001, n
w’nua pa 84 njr."""

def count(texte):
    ordre_txt = {}
    order = ""
    texte.lower()
    alfb = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    for i in range(len(alfb)):
        ordre_txt[alfb[i]] = texte.count(alfb[i])
    ordre_txt = sorted(ordre_txt.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
    for elt in ordre_txt:
        order += elt[0]
    return order


def trad2(texte):
    ordre_fr = 'esaitnruolhdcgmpvfqbjxzykw'
    ordre_txt = count(texte)

    for i in range(26):
        texte.replace(ordre_txt[i], ordre_fr[i])
        return texte

print(trad2(texte))
```

Comment: you dont do anything with `texte.replace(ordre_txt[i], ordre_fr[i])` which returns a new string that is simply discarded

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower)
   *Return a copy of the string with all the cased characters converted to lowercase.* So use `texte = texte.lower()` instead of `texte.lower()` at the 3rd line in `def count(texte):`.
2. Apply `str.translate(table)` in `def trad2(texte):` e.g. as follows:

```
def trad2(texte):
    ordre_fr = 'esaitnruolhdcgmpvfqbjxzykw'
    ordre_txt = count(texte)
    tr_table = str.maketrans(ordre_txt, ordre_fr)
    return texte.translate(tr_table)
```

3. Note the [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) static method (*returns a translation table usable for `str.translate()`*)…
   *If there are two arguments, they must be strings of equal length, and in the resulting dictionary, each character in x will be mapped to the character at the same position in y.*